Can pm2 make RAM problem like giving BDOS (BLUE SCREEN) with MEMORY MANAGMENT ERROR?
I run pm2 10 proccess with Puppeteer browser to make some quick parsing. After that several times in week I got BDOS error with MEMORY MANAGEMENT.
In Windows task manager I don't see any problem while running the script. I have 32gb RAM and Intel i3 12-th generation

But I have to add that on my second more weak computer there are not any problem with the same script like BDOS
I try to reinstall the windows 11, but there is the same BDOS screen. I also try to check memory with several tools, but in microsoft support says that it is the RAM problem
